# Writing Button Tag with rails condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write a button tag in Rails with a checking condition which appends a class..

I wrote it like this.. but causing syntax error.

```
<%= button_tag "On", {class: 'notification-btn notification-on btn btn-xs'+' active' if current_user.notification == true} %>
```

This `active` class need to be present only if current_user.notification is true

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= button_tag "On", {class: "notification-btn notification-on btn btn-xs#{' active' if current_user.notification == true}"} %>
```

Comment: A condition itself is essentially a check for whether an expression is true. No need to specify `== true` explicitly. However, in context of this question it makes the answer clearer.

Comment: @D-side thanks for the information.. so to check a boolean just the condition is enough like if current_user

Comment: @NidhinSG `if current_user.notification`, right. A condition is cast to boolean anyway.

Comment: What if i want an anchor tag like
<a class="A active">aa</a>
With no href and again active only if its satisfies condition

Comment: Something like? `<%= link_to "aa", "#", class: "A#{' active' if current_user.notification}" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator:

```
<%= button_tag('On', class: "...#{ current_user.notification ? ' active' : '' }") %>
```

You do not need compare this:

```
current_user.notification == true
```

is superfluous.

```
=> foo = true
=> true
=> puts 'baz' if foo
=> "baz"
```